# Command mv to move file not woking :- mv: cannot move : No such file or directory

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

The foll snippets explains the code in brief :-

```
define('UPLOAD_DONE_PATH','');//This comes from config
$uploaddir = '/home/upload';//This comes as functn parameter
$uploaddir_done = $uploaddir.UPLOAD_DONE_PATH;
$uploaddir_done = str_replace("//","/",$uploaddir_done);

$file_array=array();
if (is_dir($uploaddir)) {
      if ($dh = opendir($uploaddir)) {

            while (($allfile = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                if ($allfile == '.' or $allfile == '..') continue;
                {
                   if (strpos($allfile, 'abc') !== false ) {

                       $file_array[]=$allfile;

                    }
                }

            }

            closedir($dh);

      }
}

...//some code

foreach ($file_array as $key => $csvfile) {

    //Process the file.

    //Move the processed file

    // Method 1 : Not Working
    // copy file from upload to processed folder
     if (copy($uploaddir.$csvfile,$uploaddir_done.$csvfile)) {
        unlink($uploaddir.$csvfile);
        $this->log->info("CSV file is copy into destination folder.".PHP_EOL);
      }else{
          $this->log->info("CSV file is not copy into destination folder.".PHP_EOL);
      }

     //Method 2 : Also not working(Move with shell_exec)
     $from = $uploaddir.$csvfile;
     $fromSpace = $from;
        
      $to = $uploaddir_done.$csvfile;
      $toSpace = $to;
        
      $fromSpace = preg_replace('/\s/i', '\\ ', $fromSpace);
      $toSpace = preg_replace('/\s/i', '\\ ', $toSpace);
        
      $ch_permissions = 'sudo chmod +755 -R '.$fromSpace;
      $mv_cmd = 'mv '.$fromSpace.' '.$toSpace;
        
      $ch_permission_result =  shell_exec($ch_permissions);
      $file_move_result =  shell_exec($mv_cmd);
    }
}
```

In both cases, Moving the file results in error "mv: cannot move ‘/home/upload/abc 09.25.2020.csv’ to ‘/home/upload/processed/abc 09.25.2020.csv’: No such file or directory
"
It appears that this is due to space in filename.How do i go about resolving this?

Comment: just add quotes around the files `$mv_cmd = 'mv "'.$fromSpace.'" "'.$toSpace . '"';`